# Quotient group of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the group
$$
G=\left\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{matrix}\right) : a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a > 0\right\rbrace
$$
with usual matrix multiplication. Let
$$
N=\left\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right) : b\in\mathbb{R}\right\rbrace
$$
$N$ is a normal subgroup. How to form the quotient group $G/N$ in this case?

Comment: in G !st row is a b, 2nd row is 0 a^-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
The map $$G\to(0,+\infty),\quad  \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto a,$$
is a group homomorphism, where the group multiplication on $(0,+\infty)$ is simply real number multiplication.

Comment: basically that means G/N will contain all positive real nos?

Comment: @kris91: Yes. The homomorphism is surjective and its kernel is $N$, so $G/N\cong (0,+\infty)$

Comment: Let G be a group with identity element e. If x and y are elements in G
satisfying x^5*y^3 = x^8*y^5 = e, then which of the following conditions is true?
(A) x = e; y = e  
(B) x not equal to e; y = e  
(C) x = e; y not equal to e  
(D) x not equal to e; y not equal to  e


Should I consider this group to be multiplicative group?  I am not being able to post this question.

Comment: @kris91: Yes, $G$ should be considered as a multiplicative group, and (A) is true. Note that $x^5=y^{-3}$ and $x^8=y^{-5}$. Then $e=(y^{-3})^5\cdot (y^5)^3=(x^{5})^{5}\cdot (x^{-8})^3$ and $e=(x^5)^8\cdot (x^8)^{-5}=(y^{-3})^8\cdot (y^{-5})^{-5}$. Why cannot you post this question?

Comment: whenever I try to post the question I get the response that the post is not up to quality standards.  How can I be sure that the group is multiplicative?

Comment: @kris91: I dno't quite understand your question. To me, a multiplicative group is nothing but a group whose group operation is denoted by multiplication. Did you use TeX commands to format mathematical notations when your tried posting question?

Comment: What I mean is in the question it's not given anywhere that group operation is multiplication so how can I be sure that it is a multiplicative group?   I don't know how to use TeX commands.I will try to figure that out once my exams are over.